# VB.net - Get date from MySQL, add it with a month and compare it with today's date

Tags: mysql, vb.net, date

I'm making an invoice system using VB.Net and MySQL.

First of all, I have to retrieve a date from **mysql**, add it with a month and compare it with today's date.

My date format in mysql is *"yyyy-MM-dd"*

My problems are:

1. How should I **add** a month to the date which I get from **mysql**?
2. How should I **check** if that date have already exceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Get the data from MYSQL

```
Dim dateFromMySQL as DateTime = //Get from MYSQL
```

Then

1) How should I add a month to the date which I get from mysql?
   Just use `AddMonths` to add month to date.

```
Dim newDate as DateTime = dateFromMySQL.AddMonths(1)
```

2) How should I check if that date have already exceed?

```
if dateFromMySQL  <= DateTime.Now Then
```

Answer (score 0):

Look, I don't know vb.net but as it uses .Net and I know C# it's probably the same.

If you're not using an ORM, you'll have to get the date representation from MySql, convert it to a Date or DateTime object using the class constructor, and this object has methods to add a month and compare to a limit date.

I think it'll solve your problem.